# How can i use org.joda.time.LocalDate and java.time.LocalDate at the same time;

Tags: java, javafx, jodatime

I'm practicing on how to work with dates. But i got stuck when i want to use a javafx datepicker. since it only works with java.time.LocalDate i was trying something like this.

```
    // here i import java.time.LocalDate to get the date from the datepicker;

    LocalDate dueDate = datepickerInvoiceDueDate.getValue();  
    int year = dueDate.getYear();
    int month = dueDate.getMonthValue();
    int day = dueDate.getDayOfMonth();

    //but here i want to import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

    LocalDate dueDatejt = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
```

Is there a workaround for this ?
And is it possible to store Localdate (joda time) inside mysql database ?

I found a temporary fix but i do not think this is the right way ?

```
    java.time.LocalDate dueDate = datepickerInvoiceDueDate.getValue();  
    int year = dueDate.getYear();

    int month = dueDate.getMonthValue();
    int day = dueDate.getDayOfMonth();
    //import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
    LocalDate dueDatejt = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
```

Comment: You can use the fully qualified name of the class, so your temporary fix is the correct way.

Comment: *"I found a temporary fix but i do not think this is the right way ?"* And why do you think that?

Comment: Because in a large context it would be easy to get confused. So i thought there would be a better solution but as i mention in the comment of the acceptet answer i got rid of joda time and found the answers i needed here : [mscharhag/ava-8-datetime-api](http://www.mscharhag.com/2014/02/java-8-datetime-api.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u mean `LocalDate dueDatejt = new LocalDate(year, month, day);` in your "temporary fix" which is just correct code.

If u want some more definitive way of doing, I would suggest getting rid of Joda time dates, since new java 8 dates have been implemented by the creator of Joda time, you will find just the same functionnalities in a very similar API.

About inserting dates into database, u can insert dates of any type, provided u convert them to java.sql.Date (or java.sql.Timestamp/java.sql.Time) before.

For a standard java.time.LocalDate, you can do : `java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(dueDate);`

Comment: Thx for the answer. i got rid of joda time and found the answers i needed here : [mscharhag/ava-8-datetime-api](http://www.mscharhag.com/2014/02/java-8-datetime-api.html)

Answer (score 6):

The author of both libraries writes on the [Joda-Time-website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to java.time (JSR-310).

So it is clear you should use the workaround to fully qualify the classnames of Joda-Time only as temporary solution. Instead the intention and official recommendation is to migrate on Java-8-platforms.

Although there is usually no 1:1-migration (some effort is necessary!), the fact that Joda-Time will not be any longer in real development (abandoning many new features, just bugfixing) is a strong argument for migration. Another strong argument in favor of migration is the missing interoperability of Joda-Time with Java-8. The author had got the original plan to support low-level-interfaces like `TemporalAccessor` but dropped it (probably due to lack of resources). What does this concept mean? Concrete example for interoperability (leaving aside the somehow annoying fact to write fully qualified class names):

**With `TemporalAccessor`-Support you could write:**

```
org.joda.time.LocalDate joda = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(year, month, day);
java.time.LocalDate date = java.time.LocalDate.from(joda);
```

**But actually you must write:**

```
org.joda.time.LocalDate joda = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(year, month, day);
java.time.LocalDate date = java.time.LocalDate.of(joda.getYear(), joda.getMonthOfYear(), joda.getDayOfMonth());
```

So it is obvious that it is no good idea to support both libraries at the same time in your application.

Comment: something like: `LocalDate.parse(myJodaDate.toString)` is less typing

Comment: @LucasRoberts Agreed, less typing using `toString()` but: relying on that method in general is not such a good idea (although in this special case, Joda has finished status so the behaviour will not change).